# Question about shower head installation

Tags: shower

I had a new shower built/installed, but the contractor didn't finish and has stopped answering/responding to calls. I thought I'd try to finish installing the shower head/controls myself but I'm not sure what this setup is vs. what the instructions specify. Does this look right? It looks like a threaded pipe, but that's not how the shower head connects. Maybe I'm missing something. Any advice would be appreciated!

https://imgur.com/a/wmwf7vw

Comment: Are you sure those are pipes? They look more like plumber's test fittings to me, which are used to block off shower outlets so the piping can be pressure-tested, and the finish surface installed before the final fixtures go in. Looks like there are outlets for a shower head and some sort of hand-held device lower down.